# How to select integer values only from a varchar column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, numeric, varchar

How to select integer values only from a varchar column in PostgreSQL?

If the column contains:

```
abc
70
3g
71
1.5
```

I'd like to select only:

```
70
71
```

I'm struggling to find functions like: is_numeric, is_integer, to do something like this:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE isinteger(column)
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE column ~ '^\d+$'
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work fine. Mind to share a link where I can find more info about the use of the `~` symbol?

Comment: @Tom Here is the [`link`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: How do we include negative integers in the result as well?